# Navigating to the next page without submitting the current form in Laravel

Tags: navigation, laravel-pagination

I am new in Laravel, I want to make a form inserting data into it and navigate it to the next page for the user to continue completing the form without submitting the current form to the database as i am using the same table to store the data.

I have check the route and controller either there is wrong somewhere. Most of the try and error resulting the first page form, the data are submitted to the database when i click on next page button.

```
`ReportController.php`

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Report;
use App\Models\Image;

class ReportController extends Controller
{

public function store(Request $request) {
    try {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'report_name' => 'required',
            'client_name' => 'required',
            'location'=>'required',
            'date'=>'required',
            'end_date'=>'required',
            'item'=>'required',
            'technique'=>'required',
            'equipment'=>'required',
            'probe'=>'required',
            'prelim'=>'required',
            'extend_inspect'=>'required',
            'scanning_tech'=>'required',
            'pic'=>'required',
            'result'=>'required'
        ]);

        // Create a new Report and store it in the session
        $report = Report::create($data);
        $request->session()->put('report_id', $report->id);

        return redirect()->route('image1');  // Redirect to the next page
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return back()->with('error', 'An error occurred while saving the data.');
        }
}
```

`ImageController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Report;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Image;

class ImageController extends Controller
{ 

    public function store(Request $request){
        try{
            $data = $request->validate([
            'img_title'=>'required',
            'img_remark'=>'required'
        ]);
        $reportId = $request->session()->get('report_id');
        $data['report_id']= $reportId;
        Image::create($data);
        $new_report = Report::create($data);
        if($request->has('images')){
            foreach($request->file('images') as $image){
                $imageName = $data['img_title'] . '-image'.time().rand(1,1000).'.'.$image->extension();
                $image->move(public_path('report_images'), $imageName);
                Image::create([
                    'report_id'=>$new_report->id,
                    'image' =>$imageName
            ]);
        }
        }
    return back()->with('success','Added');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Log the error or handle it appropriately
    return back()->with('error', 'An error occurred while saving the data.');
    }

}
}
```

`web.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Http\Controllers\ReportController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ImageController;

Route::get('/index', [ReportController::class, 'create'])->name('create-index');
Route::post('/index', [ReportController::class, 'store'])->name('store-index');

Route::get('/image1' , [ImageController::class, 'showImage1']) ->name('image1');
Route::post('/image1', [ImageController::class, 'store'])->name('store-image1');
```

`index.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

<main class="container">
<section>
    <!-- Include the CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

<!-- Include the JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <form action="/report" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
            <div class="titlebar">
                <a href=" {{route('report.create')}}" class='btn-link'>View</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
               <div>
                    <label>Report Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="report_name">

                    <label>Client</label>
                    <input type="text" name="client_name">
                  <!--  <textarea cols="10" rows="5" ></textarea> 
                    <label>Add Image</label>
                    <img src="" alt="" class="img-product" id="file.preview"/>
                    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" onchange="showFile(event)">
                </div> -->
               
                    <label>Location</label>
                    <input type="text"name="location">

                    <label>From</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date">

                    <label>To</label>
                    <input type="date" name="end_date">

                    <label>Item</label>
                    <input type="text" name="item">

                    <label>Technique</label>
                    <select  name="technique" name="technique" input type="category">
                        @foreach (json_decode('{"Time-of-Flight Diffraction (TOFD)":"Time-of-Flight Diffraction (TOFD)","Phased Array Ultrasonic (PAUT)":"Phased Array Ultrasonic (PAUT)","Time-of-Flight Diffraction (TOFD) & Phased Array Ultrasonic (PAUT)":"Time-of-Flight Diffraction (TOFD) & Phased Array Ultrasonic (PAUT)"}',true) as $optionKey =>$optionValue)
                        <option value="{{$optionKey}}" >{{$optionValue}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                    <label>Equipment</label>
                    <input type="text" name="equipment">

                    <label>Probe</label>
                    <select name="probe" id="probe" input type="category">
                        @foreach (json_decode('{"15Mhz 3mmØ with wedge 70°":"15Mhz 3mmØ with wedge 70°","A32-5L64 with Wedge SA32-N55S":"A32-5L64 with Wedge SA32-N55S"}', true) as $optionKey => $optionValue)
                        <option value="{{ $optionKey }}">{{ $optionValue }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>

                    <label>Preliminary Report</label>
                    <textarea cols="10" rows="8" name="prelim"> All data recorded from this inspection will be kept for result comparison in future monitoring. </textarea>
                    
                    <label>End of Inspection</label>
                    <textarea cols="10" rows="8" name="extend_inspect"> Refer to attached drawing for detail of weld seams tested and scanning direction. </textarea>

                    <label>Scanning Technique </label>
                    <textarea cols="10" rows="12" name="scanning_tech"> It must be noted that material thickness is proportional to the square root of time measurement indicated in the Y-axis.</textarea>

                    <label>Client Representative</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pic">

                    <label>Result</label>
                    <textarea cols="10" rows="5" name="result">Weld defects / weld deposit during fabrication was found during the time of inspections. </textarea>

                        
                </div> 
            </div> 
            
            <div class="save-button">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" href=" {{route('image1')}}" class='btn-link'>Next</button>
            </div>  

</form>
</section>
</main>
@endsection
```

`image1.blade.php`

```
@section('content')

<main class="container">
<div class="row-justify-content-between">

    @if (session('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert"></button>
        <h4>Success</h4>
    </div>
    @endif
    
    <div class="col-md-5">
    <h5>Section 1</h5>

    <form action="{{route('store-image1')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="img_title">Title</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control"
                name="img_title"
                placeholder="Title">

                <span class="text-danger">
                    @error('img_title')
                        {{$message}}
                    @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="img_remark">Remark</label>
            <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control "
                name="img_remark"
                placeholder="Remark">

                <span class="text-danger">
                    @error('img_remark')
                        {{$message}}
                    @enderror
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="files" class="form-label mt-4">Upload Image (s)</label>
            <input
                type="file"
                name="images[]"
                class="form-control"
                accept="image/*"
                multiple>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mt-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</main>

@endsection
```